# missing entries in tclIndex for snit types

Tags: tcl

I'm using tcl 8.6 which included snit (Active State Tcl).
My snit types are held in different files. When generating an index with `auto_mkindex` the relevant stuff for the snit types  is missing in `tclIndex`.

That means:
when I try to create an object of snit type 
(for example 
    '`MYTYPE create objectsName ...`),
the interpreter writes a message
        `invalid command name ....`

If I complete tclIndex manually

```
set auto_index(RPCSkeleton) [list source [file join $dir rpc2.tcl]]
```

everything runs fine!

Do I get something wrong? Is this a bug in the snit package (or in an add on module for `auto_mkindex`)?

Comment: I've never used `auto_mkindex`, so have no first-hand knowledge. However, [the wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1694) starts by stating "Note - if you want to use auto_mkindex with itcl or any other extension that declares special proc-like constructs, be certain to do a package require of the extension first." Did you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't advise using `auto_mkindex` at all; the whole thing it does with setting up automatically-loaded code is rather ill-advised in the first place in any real application. It's far better to either:

1. Assemble the code into a package which you can `package require`. The package definition file will require a `package provide` call in it, and you'll then want to (at least the first time) use `pkg_mkIndex` to create the package index file. Package index files are simple enough that you'll then be able to maintain them by hand; they don't list every command in the package in them, and are relocatable, so maintenance is just adding an extra file if necessary and occasionally updating the version number. (Do *not* use lazy package loading!)

   Alternatively, …
2. Directly `source` the files at the right time. This is most useful for where you've got an application whose source is longer than you want to put in a single file. (Splitting things up can be a very good instinct.)